# I made mistakes and want to simply go back a few commits on Git

Tags: git, github

I have used git reset [SHA] and it works but when I try to make a push to origin master I get this message ! "[rejected] HEAD -> master (non-fast-forward)". I have no idea what to do at this point? If I make a pull it seems to bring back all the changes I tried to get rid of.

Comment: Have the commits you want to undo been pushed in the remote git repository (origin masteR)? Check this guide: https://github.com/blog/2019-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want to overwrite the master branch on the remote, you'll need to force push:

```
git push -f origin master
```

**But warning!** If others are using this repository you may cause them a lot of problems by doing this. If so, you should probably create a commit reverting the unwanted commits instead (see [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/283078)).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the message you are getting is a [non-fast-forward-error](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/), meaning your push is being refused because another person has pushed to the same branch you pushed to. To be able to make your pushes, you need to first run a `git fetch origin`, origin being the name you gave the remote. Then running a `git status` to make sure you're in the clear. After, run a `git merge origin YOUR_BRANCH_Name`, to [merge](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/) the changes made online with those you made locally.